# Facebook and Firefox iFrame error

Tags: facebook, firefox, iframe

I have a facebook application set up as an iFrame app that refuses to load on Firefox 3.6 + 4.0 for both Mac and PC.

The backend server is only presenting an HTML "Hello World" page. The application loads the content from the server 1/10 times using the Firefox, but loads perfectly fine on Chrome, Safari and IE. Firebug identifies the perpetual loading of 0.100.channel.facebook.com.

Has anyone else encountered this issue? I have tested other Facebook applications and other machines with Firefox. They all seem to have the same problem.

I'd appreciate any help you could offer.

Answer (score 2):

As my experience goes FF doesn not allow to load sites which accept cookies to be loaded in an IFrame.